# How do I reverse words not the characters using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to reverse the words of a text file:

If my input is:

```
Hello World
```

My output should be:

```
World Hello
```

I tried this:

```
File.open('teste.txt').each_line do |line|
  print line.reverse.gsub(/\n/,"")
end
```

but I got the characters reversed.

Comment: Gabriel, I would like to offer a small suggestion regarding the phrasing of questions.  Sometimes, as here, it's a bit difficult to be precise without getting into awkward sentence construction. In such cases a picture is often worth 1K words, e.g., 'I want to reverse each line of a text file so that "The fox jumped" becomes "jumped fox The"'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
"Hello World".split.reverse.join(" ")
=> "World Hello"
```

It splits the string into an array with a whitespace being the default delimiter. Then it reverses the array and concatenates the strings in the array using a white space as well.

Your solution should look like this:

```
File.open("test.txt").each_line do |line|
  puts line.split.reverse.join(" ")
end
```

`puts` appends a linebreak after the output, while `print` does not. This is neccessary, because `split` discards the original linebreak on each line, when splitting it into an array of words.

Comment: `File.open("test.txt").each_line` should look like `File.foreach("test.txt")`

Answer (score 2):

Break string into words and reverse that.

```
"Hello World".split.reverse.join(' ') # => "World Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on spaces, reverse it, then join them together.

You could make a method to do it as such:

```
def reverse_words(string)
      return string.split(" ").reverse.join(" ")
end
```

then later, call that method with:

```
print reverse_words("Hello World")
```

Or set a string to the returned value:

```
reversed_string = reverseWords("Hello World")
```

Comment: In Ruby we use snake_case for method names and variables, not camelCase. `reversedString` and `reverseWords` should be `reversed_string` and `reverse_words` respectively.

Comment: Right, sorry, I know that. I've been doing a lot of programming in Java. I'll edit that.